# Jenkins jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfiguratorException

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

Am new and have problem while build jenkins on dockerfile in localhost.

error:

```
io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfiguratorException: No configurator for the following root elements jobs
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.invokeWith(ConfigurationAsCode.java:734)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.checkWith(ConfigurationAsCode.java:776)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.configureWith(ConfigurationAsCode.java:761)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.configureWith(ConfigurationAsCode.java:637)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.configure(ConfigurationAsCode.java:306)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.init(ConfigurationAsCode.java:298)
Caused: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:104)
Caused: java.lang.Error
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:110)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder$TaskImpl.run(TaskMethodFinder.java:180)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1151)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:282)
    at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:49)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:1184)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:976)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:85)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:81)
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:298)
Caused: hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:315)
```

> If anyone need file to debug/see process it, please tell me and i will edit the post with add file required. Thank you

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGw5N.jpg

Comment: i've been having the same problem recently. I have two Jenkins both on the same version 2.289.3. One has this plugin working fine but the other is failing with the same error as above. Its failing on the plugin extensions with 'java.lang.Error; java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException'

Comment: Actualy is related for the version jenkins or plugin @scrow , not sure but you can try for another version and re-test it. hopefully running properly~

Comment: I meant to add this at the time. I figured out the issue for my jenkins. It seemed to have a requirement for another plugin, job-dsl, specifically version 1.74 of this plugin. Having this fixed the issue